# Hide window from taskbar

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to minimize a window to the tray, but it seems it refuses to hide from the taskbar. I've spent a little time and distilled the problem code down to this. It's not mcuh so I'm wondering if I need something else to hide my app to tray in Windows 7.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import uic 
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QApplication

class MyClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(os.path.join("gui", "timeTrackerClientGUI.ui"), self)
    def hideEvent(self, event):
        self.hide()
    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = MyClass()
    wnd.show()
    app.exec_()
```

It seems the application icon does hide but then another one pops up, If I click the taskbar icon multiple times I can get these two icons flickering, looks kind of like this for a splitsecond before the first one hides:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a quite ugly hack to get it working but here's the final code if anybody is interested, ph is my platform-specific module, you can use platform.name or similar function instead:

```
def hideEvent(self, event):
    self.hide()
    if ph.is_windows():
        self.hidden = True
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.ToolTip)
def showEvent(self, event):
    if ph.is_windows() and self.hidden:
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window)
        self.hidden = False
    self.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

calling show/hide in showEvent()/hideEvent() doesn't make sense - those events are the result of show()/hide() calls (and the like), not the trigger. If you want to toggle the window visiblity by clicking the tray icon, try setVisible(!isVisible()) on the widget, if you want to hide the window when the user clicks the window close button try reimplementing closeEvent():

```
MyMainWindow::closeEvent( QCloseEvent* e ) {
    hide();
    e->accept();
}
```

In Python, that is

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.hide()
    event.accept()
```

Comment: I want to hide the window so it doesn't show in taskbar when I minimize it.

Comment: Minimized windows are always shown in the taskbar, to my knowledge. If you want to remove it, you have to hide it. Also, I'd consider a window that disappears when clicking the minimize button awkward and not well-behaved for a UI application. If one wants to remove it, one has to close it instead of minimizing. (that said, I'm not a regular windows user, maybe I missed some de-facto interface guideline here). If you really want to do that, You probably have to listen for QWindowStateChangeEvent, i.e. call hide() when receiving it and ignore()ing the event.

Comment: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#hideEvent The window recieves a spontaneous hide event then the user minimizes the window, so then I want to hide it from taskbar and only show tray icon but I've tried both hide() and setVisible(False) and nothing hides it from the taskbar. Frank: I'm trying to implement minimize-to-tray, a behaviour that commonly can be opted into in windows.